# interval statistic with month name column

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

Last time I used interval, but I don't think it work like I want to,
 I just want to declare year and month. Can any guru can teach me here?

This is sample data as request:

```
food_type | sales | date_sales
   pizza     buy     02-01-2015 12:00:00
   pizza     buy     02-01-2015 03:00:00
   pizza     sell     03-01-2015 01:00:00
   pizza     sell     04-01-2015 05:00:00
   pizza     buy     05-01-2015 02:00:00
```

This is sample I am trying to do

```
DECLARE @Startdate AS datetime = '02-01-2015',
 @Enddate AS datetime = '05-01-2015'


SELECT TYPE_FOOD, COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'BUY' THEN 1 END) AS [INCOMING], COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS= 'SELL' THEN 1 END) AS [OUTGOING]
FROM Shop WHERE [Something_Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

OR

```
SELECT TYPE_FOOD, COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'BUY' THEN 1 END) AS [INCOMING], COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS= 'SELL' THEN 1 END) AS [OUTGOING],DATEDIFF(MONTH, DATE_OF_PURCHASE, @YEAR ) AS [YEAR]  
FROM Shop 
GROUP BY TYPE_FOOD, DATEDIFF(MONTH,DATE_OF_PURCHASE, @YEAR )
```

-- i cant use datediff because i want between date..

This the closest query I can get if using `datediff`...not year only anymore...

```
Food TYPE | MONTH | BUY | SELL 
 pizza       12     10     5       
 pizza       13      3     1       
 ....        ...     ..     ..     
 pizza       32     5      2
```

How can I make the sql output like this:

```
Food TYPE | MONTH   |   BUY | SELL | 
 pizza       Feb-15     10    5        
 pizza       Mar-15     3     1       
 ....        ...       ..     ..     
 pizza       May-15     5     2
```

Please help me guru, I am still very beginner in sql

Comment: Can you please add some sample data

Comment: @TheGameiswar ok i add some sample

Comment: yes within the invertal of month @TheGameiswar

Comment: ermm noone can answer me ? is it very hard?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need a sum and  a group by type_food

```
 select TYPE_FOOD, date_format(date_sales, '%m -  %Y'),
 sum(case when sales = 'buy' then 1 else 0 end) as incoming,
 sum(case when sales = 'sell' then 1 else 0 end) as outgoing
 from shop
 group by type_food
```

Comment: i using sql server 2008 , i cant use date_form,, is that like datepart? @scaisEdge

Comment: I'sorry but in you tag there is mysql  .. i think the equivalent is  FORMAT(yourdate, 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'en-US' )